# AngularJS - my datetimepicker does not display calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetimepicker

I'd like to have dropdown datepicker on my page.

Here is my code:

```
<code>http://plnkr.co/edit/UaD8A06ilA6K6MsDL95s?p=preview</code>
```

The problem is that the menu with the calendar does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <input type="text" ng-focus="startOpened = true; endOpened = false;" ng-click="startOpen($event)" show-button-bar="false" close-text="Close" ng-required="true" max-date="end" min-date="'1970-12-31'" is-open="startOpened" show-weeks="false" ng-model="startDate" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" placeholder="Start date...">
```

This is example of datepicker which angular ui provides. 
Make different flags for ng-focus, ng-open.

Here's that link for more options.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup